# Probability $P(S)$ of certain event $S$ is $0$

Tags: probability, probability-theory, exponential-distribution

Consider the following event: $S:= \{  \sup_n  \ \tau_n < \infty\} $

$\tau_n- \tau_{n-1}=T_n $, where $T_n \sim exp( a_n) $

$(a_n)$ is a sequence of positive numbers in $\mathbb{R}$

Suppose: $ \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{a_n} = \infty$

How can I show that $P(S)=0$?

Comment: You never use $S$, and you didn't introduce $A$ -- perhaps these two were meant to be the same?

Comment: @joriki: Yes they are the same

Answer (score 2):

If $\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac1{a_n} = \infty$, then $\prod_{n=1}^\infty(1+1/a_n)=\infty$. By monotone convergence and independence,
$$
\mathbb E\left[e^{-\sum_{n=1}^\infty T_n} \right] = \prod_{n=1}^\infty \mathbb E[e^{-T_n}] = \prod_{n=1}^\infty\left(1+\frac1{a_n}\right)^{-1} = 0,
$$
so $$\mathbb P\left( \sum_{n=1}^\infty T_n = \infty\right) = 1. $$

Comment: How can you conclude, that $\mathbb E\left[e^{-\sum_{n=1}^\infty T_n} \right]=0 \Rightarrow \mathbb P\left( \sum_{n=1}^\infty T_n = \infty\right) = 1. $